# How to get Composer to leave a package alone

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two packages that was pulled to my project with composer.

I don't want to have composer pull updates on these packages from anywhere and don't want composer to try and override my files with any repository.

If I remove the packages from my composer.json file it deletes the packages an removes the autoloaders.

How do I get composer to leave the packages alone and allow me to work on the code without losing the files or autoloaders on update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

What you want to do is create an artifact directory.

Thus in your main composer.json file you need to do something like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "artifact",
        "url": "custom/artifact/"
    },
    ..........
```

the url var should be the file path to the zip files relative to composer.json file.

Now you only need to add a composer.json file with a name and version to a zip file.

If the package already contains a composer.json file you only need to add a version.

example:
vendor-package-1.0.zip needs a composer.json file with:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "vendor/package",
    "type": "library",
    ........... etc
}
```

It is important to define the version in the composer.json file or it will not find it.

Now you call this package by version from your projects composer file:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package": "1.0",
```

Now you can create and update files in your package without the worry that some online change or offline server will cause any problems.

As long as the version stays the same it should leave your files alone.

The good thing is that files added or removed will still update the autoloaders as specified in the zip package's composer.json file.

Answer (score 2):

Give a specific version for that package, so it will not be updated when new versions come up

If you don't have too many packages, you can use

```
composer update package1 package2
```

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. The only problem problem with your answer is that it still needs to link to some online library with versions. If there is no version specified and there is only a master you run in to problems. I needed it to be stand alone since the online library was deleted after i pulled it in. The only solution I could find is to use an artifact as explained in my answer below.